# https non www to https www

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i rewrite all non-www requests to www with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But...
this doesn´t work with https, so I also want all https requests without www to https with www.
Example:

```
https : // mydomain . de --> https : // www . mydomain . de
https://mydomain.de/example --> https://www.mydomain.de/example
```

Con someone help me here?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
## add www to a domain name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This will perform:

- https => https with www rewrite
- http => http with www rewrite